# Digit Span Test in Python that needs OOP

Tags: python, oop

I'm working on a school project due in a few days, it's a digit span test in python that requires the implementation of Object Orient Programming. Here's what I got so far,

```
import time
import random
import os

appeartimeframe = float(1)
os.system('cls')
print("Welcome to the digit span test.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')
time.sleep(1)
print("We hope you enjoy.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')

randomlist = []
def start():
    game_state = 0
    a = 5
    while game_state == 0:
        for i in range(0,a):
            n = random.randint(1,9)
            randomlist.append(n)

        print(randomlist, sep = "\n")
        arr = []

        for i in range(0, a):
            answer = int(input("enter answer "))
            arr.append(answer)

        if arr == randomlist:
            print("nice")
        else: 
            print("uh oh")
            game_state = 1


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        gamediff = int(input("Input Difficulty ( 1 - 4 ):  "))
        if gamediff == 1:
            print("Difficulty [ EASY ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 2
            start()
        elif gamediff == 2:
            print("Difficulty [ MEDIUM ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 1.6
            start()
        elif gamediff == 3:
            print("Difficulty [ HARD ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 1.2
            start()
        elif gamediff == 4:
            print("Difficulty [ VIRTUALLY IMPOSSIBLE ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 0.7
            start()
        else:
            print("Invalid Difficulty selected.")
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How the code works is that it welcomes you to the test, lets you choose the difficulty ( not implemented yet ) and then prints out a random array ( for testing purposes ). Here are a few of the problems I've got so far:

- After correctly guessing the array, instead of adding one more digit, it adds 5 more.
- I have no idea how to individually print out each element in the array.
- Probably a lot more that I don't know about.

Comment: **1)** appending to array is within a `for i in range(0, a):` loop where `a==5` **2)** print one element using indexing like `print(array[your_index])` **3)** exiting the game by choosing a wrong difficulty is not really intuitive; you use _comparison_, not _assignment_ with `appeartimeframe`

Comment: "*needs OOP*" and "*implementation of Object Orient Programming*" probably means you should be using **classes**. As a question on SO, it is very much unclear what exactly/specifically does the teacher expect from you from this assignment.